# Visual studio, auto generating code acting weird

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to write a web form in Visual Studio with C# and asp.net.

If I put a `button` in a `design` tab and double click it (so the code would be auto-generated), this happens in a `html .aspx` file.

```
<script runat="server">

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub
</script>
```

For some reason I get VB.NET code although I use C#. If I manually put the code in `aspx.cs` file, the button is not detected ("the method is never used" is shown).

Comment: are you sure your project is set up to use C# rather than VB?

Comment: This is visual basic, I'm going to guess you set up the wrong project

Comment: _Why do people keep confusing these two languages??_

Comment: I know it is VB, but I'm 100% I chose C# as language when I created the project.

Comment: What if you create a new project?

Comment: Same thing happens. I'm trying to repair Visual Studio right now, maybe this will help.

Comment: Strange... If this truly was a C# project the VB.NET code would give you errors. If the problem persist after repair: what happens if you manually write C# code?

Comment: Yes, the VB code is giving me errors everywhere. C# code is not giving me any errors but I can't connect the code with elements (buttons etc.)

Comment: Try setting the `onclick` attribute or just add an event handler in `Page_Load`.

Comment: I made a rollback to the initial state of the question and added a sentence clarifying that you're getting auto-generated code in the wrong language.

Comment: onclick attribute wasn't working. I repaired visual studio, created new project, now it is somehow working. Thank you for your time!